# Cycle through multiple cursors to enter different text at each point?

Tags: multiple-cursors

When multiple cursors has marked multiple points in a buffer you can use `C-v` (`mc/cycle-forward`) to cycle through and look through all cursors while typing for all cursors.  I'm wondering how to enter different text at each cursor point while retaining the `mc/cycle-forward` cycling behavior or working with mc as seamlessly as possible.

A rough use case (possibly positioning #5 after #7):

1. `mc/mark-all-like-this` or equivalent to create multiple cursors
2. [usual mc interaction with all cursors]
3. [some action to indicate interaction with a single cursor]
4. enter text at current cursor
5. hit `C-v` an arbitrary number of times to select a different cursor
6. enter text / move point of a now different current cursor
7. [some action to restore standard mc behavior]
8. [resume interaction with all cursors]

I currently use `isearch-forward` to fill in for this (for example to fill in different section headers in an html document), but this drops me out of mc and forces me to re-mark.

Comment: How about using [helm-swoop](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/emacs-swoop) instead? Search what you want then enter edit mode to enter different text.

Comment: Finally got around to trying helm swoop :-D  That's really nice!  It even lets you use multiple cursors in the edit mode!  Is there a way to access context of matching lines in the edit mode?

Comment: See [multiline behavior](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop#multiline-behavior).

Comment: Another way (of course there are many) might be to use M-x occur (M-s o) to find what you want, switch into the *Occur* buffer, press 'e' for occur-edit-mode, change what you want (using multiple cursors if you want) and then C-c C-c when finished.

Comment: You can try `query-replace` with `recursive-edit` (bound to `C-r` when `query-replace` is active) if you are trying to replace a few strings in a buffer. Recursive edit would let you freeze the `query-replace`, make some specific changes at point and let you resume the unfinished `query-replace` command.